# Handling multiple select values in ASP.net MVC with a service layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have many multiple select dropdowns in my asp.net mvc application and am wondering what is the best way to handle transferring those values from my viewmodel to my model. The model is then saved to the database using ef6 (I'm using db first by the way to create my entities).

Currently one of my viewmodels looks something like this:

```
     public class someviewmodel{
       public string[] selectedIds
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectValues
       //other properties
     }
```

I decided to create a partial model class and add the selectedIds to it like:

```
public partial class somemodel{
 public string[] selectedIds
 //other properties
}
```

My model is then passed to my service layer:

```
public class someservicelayer{
     public int InsertSomething(somemodel model){
      //do stuff

       if (model.selectedIds.Length != 0){
                model.SelectValues = _context.SelectValues
                    .Where(b => model.selectedIds.Contains(b.Id.ToString())).ToList();
            }
     }
   }
```

It feels wrong that I have to add a custom property in a partial class to my model.  Is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: I have a similar set up, although I've not created a partial class. My view model is composed of domain objects. This object has dropdownValue1 & dropdownValue2 as properties for the selected drop down values to bind to. This object is then passed into my service layer. So i think it's fine...the 1st someViewModel class looks ok to me with the selectid's being held there.

Comment: @Wheels73.  Hey thanks for the comment.  Are you saying you pass your viewmodel to your service layer.  From what ive read the service layer should be ignorant of any viewmodels.  It should act upon Models only.  Only what ive read when researching though.

Comment: Hello.. not the whole view model, just the domain object that hangs off the view model. So e.g...  MyViewModel.CustomerOrder..  where CustomerOrder is a domain object. This has 2 values, dropdownval1 and 2. You can then pass the customer order object in to the service layer which then keeps in line with the service layer being ignorant of the view model.. which is very correct! :)

Comment: @Wheels73 oh ok, so your service layer method would take in the domain objects. e.g somemethod(object1fromviewmodel, object2fromviewmodel)?

Comment: Yes that's right. I have all my domain objects in a separate project that can then be referenced by service and data layers. Data layer passes data set to service layer, service passes populated object to controller to be set on the view model.. this then works in reverse for saving. data.

Comment: @Wheels73 That sounds close to how i have it.  My data layer and entity layers are seperate projects. Im just wondering whether its worth me doing some refactoring and removing the selectedids from my model and just passing in the actual selectids array from my viewmodel to my service as a parameter

Comment: Yeah I would.... at this moment there's no need for anything else. You can always refactor later if needs be. I always say to myself.. "don't try to solve tomorrows problems today".. if that makes sense.